# Is there any way to apply styles or formatting for the karate log statements?

Tags: karate

Currently, Karate is generating the HTML results using plain text only. I am just wondering if there is any way to apply little formatting or styles to make the HTML result statements look pretty and catchy?

I tried adding few formatting tags to karate.log() statements, but the tags are considered as text only. For example as given below,
when *karate.log("<b>SUCCESS!!!</b>")* used, karate printed it as '<b>SUCCESS!!!</b>' in html output file. But I wanted it to display as **SUCCESS!!!**

Looking for any kind of insight or help in this matter. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can write your own report, but it needs some work. the linked q & a has details. else please assume that this is not supported (unless you contribute code)